# Google form timestamp date

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, nested-if

I am looking to timestamp my invoices via google forms.

[image]

I've tried numerous formulas, but they all seem to fall apart during the form submission.

```
=left(B2:B,(LEN(B2:B)-(FIND(" ",B2:B)-1)))
```

[image]

but it's causing the form to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need arrayformula. delete everything in C column and use this in C1:

```
={"Invoice date"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="";;TEXT(B2:B; "m/d/e")))}
```

or freeze it:

```
={"Invoice date"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(INDIRECT("B2:B")="";;TEXT(INDIRECT("B2:B"); "m/d/e")))}
```

Comment: so when I submit a form it changes the formula to 

={"Invoice date"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B3:B="",,TEXT(B3:B, "m/d/e")))}

Comment: @cpaone are you sure this happens? it shouldnt

Comment: Yes, so it appears to mess up the first form submission but I fix it and subsequent submissions seem to work flawlessly. I'm fine with that though, much better than what I had.

Comment: @cpaone try the 2nd fx from updated answer

Comment: looks like it works! ty!